# How to change my Mercurial web interface aspect

Tags: html, css, interface, mercurial, mercurial-extension

I started using mercurial now, and I have the web interface on localhost/hg.

Now I wanted to change the graphic aspect of the Mercurial page, change the look.
(CSS, icon, icon_link, ...)

I've searched everywhere and can not find anything about it.

Someone tell me how to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done it myself so I can't help more than pointing you to the hgweb theming documentation which is [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Theming).

(I'm assuming that you are using `hgweb` to publish the repositories)

Comment: Yes I am using the `hgweb`. I've seen this documentation, but it has several limitations. If there was an extension that would help in changing the interface of the page...
But, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. In my case I use ubuntu:
in `/usr/share/mercurial/templates/paper`
we find the index.tmpl where we can change the logoimg and logourl:

```
{header}
<title>Mercurial repositories index</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
<a href="{logourl}">
<img src="{staticurl}{logoimg}" width=75 height=90 border=0 alt="mercurial" /></a>
</div>
<div class="main">
<h2>Mercurial Repositories</h2>

<table class="bigtable">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="?sort={sort_name}">Name</a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort={sort_description}">Description</a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort={sort_contact}">Contact</a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort={sort_lastchange}">Last modified</a></th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    {entries%indexentry}
</table>
</div>
</div>
{footer}
```

for example if We want to change the logo url in template(e.g. paper template) we need to change in all tmpl files where the logourl exist.

```
$:/usr/share/mercurial/templates/paper$ grep logourl *
bookmarks.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
branches.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
changeset.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
error.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
fileannotate.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
filediff.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
filelog.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
filerevision.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
graph.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
help.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
helptopics.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
search.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
shortlog.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
tags.tmpl:<a href="{logourl}">
```

I hope this can help someone with the same problem.